# Transfer characteristic of two-cascade resistive voltage divider

Tags: voltage-divider, transfer-function

Transfer of a simple voltage divider with two resistors (R1 upper and R2 lower) is: $$ \frac{R2}{R1+R2}$$

Now I would like to have a two-cascade divider that looks like this:
[image: two-cascade divider]

Since the output of the first cascade (R1&R2) is connected to the input of the second cascade (R3&R4), we can multiply individual transfer functions which gives us:

$$ \frac{R2 R4}{(R1+R2)(R3+R4)} $$

However, this is incorrect. The correct answer is:

$$ \frac{R2 R4}{(R1+R2)(R3+R4)+R1R2} $$

Question. Where does R1R2 in the denominator come from?

Comment: The original transfer functions were derived assuming that the same current passing through `R1` was also passing through `R2`. Once connected together, The `R3,R4` combination draws some of the current passing through `R1`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you had a buffer amplifier with gain of 1 between the stages then the first equation would be correct (assuming no load on the output).

Since the second voltage divider loads the first one, the output signal is affected, and obviously will be less than in the non-interacting case.

The loaded output of the first voltage divider becomes Rx/(Rx + R1) where Rx = R2 || (R3+R4).

Remaining algebra is left as an exercise.

---

Edit: As mentioned above, the **loading** of the first network by the second alters the transfer function so we cannot simply modify the individual (unloaded) G1(s), G2(s) transfer functions to get the result G1(s)*G2(s) for the total transfer function.

Comment: I completely agree with you. The second cascade loads the first one and it affects the result. We can do nodal voltage or mesh current analysis to show Vout/Vin BUT I am curious how to express that properly in terms of combining the two transfer functions.

Comment: Multiple the two transfer functions together. You have to use the equation I showed above for the first transfer function.

Comment: Again, I agree with this and this is how I've got the right answer as shown in the post. My question isn't "find the transfer for the given circuit" but rather why doesn't simple multiplication of transfer functions in s domain give us the right answer if the two systems are connected in series? If we have stimulus R(s) and two consecutive systems with G1(s) and G2(s), shouldn't the transfer be G1(s)G2(s)R(s)?

Comment: (And each system taken individually has transfer Rx/(Rx+Ry), where Rx is lower resistance and Ry is upper resistance.)

Comment: The loading of the second network affects the first so the transfer function is not the same as it would be unloaded. This is a fundamental issue. When you get to passive network syntheses you'll find cascading filter sections without an intermediate buffer has similar effects- the sections interact. When we cascade active filters it can simplify things.

Comment: Right, so to summarize your answer, transfer functions cannot be simply multiplied because of loading effects. Simple "G1(s)G2(s)R(s)" shouldn't give the total output transfer function.

Comment: Yes. Of course if the transfer function was insensitive to loading (say it had an op-amp buffer after it, or if you judged that the loading was negligible because (R3 + R4) >> R2 then multiplying them is valid.

Comment: Please summarize in your answer above that we can't simply divide the whole big system and take "individual/intrinsic" transfer functions with their subsequent multiplication in s domain to get the total transfer function, so I mark your answer as accepted.